# blocking key-press signals while handling one currently

Tags: gtk

Using gtk ..how do I block another key-press signal while handling one? the handler takes 10 seconds to return.until then,it should'nt get interrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your keyhandler takes 10 seconds you should *not* run it entirely within the main context. If it possible (i.e. not related to UI drawing or UI modifications) then use a separate g_thread and handle it there.

Anyways - you are looking for `g_signal_handler_block` and `g_signal_handler_unblock` http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-handler-block

The event handler will block redrawing of your widgets until it completes!

Comment: well it is for a small game. only one arrow key need to be detected at a time. and until the animation for that key is complete,no other keypress should be emitted.

Comment: Updated answer, you should really not block the main context for 10seconds.

Comment: What did your "no" refer to?